# @Autowired Bean is NULL in Spring Boot JUnit Test

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to write the unit test case for the below file.

RoleDataController.Java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/updateRoleData")

public class RoleDataController extends ControllerBase {
    @Autowired
    public EntityManager entityManager;
    public Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    RoleData _roleData = new RoleData();
    @RequestMapping("/getRoleData")
    public String findRoleData(){
        List roleList =_roleData.findRoleData(session,123456);
        return JsonHelper.toJson(roleList);
    }
}
```

RoleDataControllerTest.java

```java
public class RoleDataControllerTest {
    RoleData _roleData = new RoleData();
    @Autowired
    public EntityManager entityManager;
    public Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    @Test
    public void findRoleData() throws Exception {
        List roleList =_roleData.findRoleData(session, 123456);
        Assert.assertNotNull(roleList);
    }
}
```

I'm getting NullPointerException in the below line

`public Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);`

Please help to fix this.

Comment: You're missing the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. Here's 
 an example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests don't start the Spring context and so the `@Autowired` annotation won't work - no dependency injection will be done by Spring. You either want to write an integration test or mock the behaviour of other beans.

Comment: Could you please help to write the integration test for the same

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html - it covers testing Spring Boot applications.

Comment: Please provide the sample test of my class